# Twilio application error when recording exceeds length

Tags: node.js, twilio

In my application, I set a recording limit for a user (60 seconds). If the user exceeds this length in their recording, Twilio plays the "An application error has occurred message."

Instead of playing this message, I want Twilio to simply hangup (instead of telling the user an error occurred).

How would I do this? This is my current code.

```js
twiml.say("Hello...");

twiml.record({
      action: "/nowhere",
      method: "POST",
      maxLength: recordingLength,
      recordingStatusCallback: config.get("RECORDING_CALLBACK")
});

twiml.hangup();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your problem here is using the `action` attribute to point to `"/nowhere"`. I am assuming that `"/nowhere"` does indeed go nowhere.

When the [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) is finished, including when it hits its [`maxLength`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-maxlength), Twilio will make a request to the `action` attribute to find out what to do next. If the URL doesn't respond with TwiML too, then you will hear the error message. Because `<Record>` always calls its `action` or the current document URL when it is complete, then having TwiML after the `<Record>` won't work. So you need to point the `action` to `"/somewhere"` instead and that endpoint should return the TwiML to [`<Hangup>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/hangup).

```
var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
twiml.hangup();
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: As a short followup, how can I play a sound (like a beep) to notify the caller that there's 10 seconds of recording time left?

Comment: Sadly there isn't an easy way to play a warning sound like that. You could try to hack it by recording a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference), but that's not possible with `<Record>`. If I answered your original question, would you mind marking it as solved so that others that see this post know it worked? Thanks!